# Are there any Lua compilers with Skype interaction libraries?

Tags: lua, skype

Is there a Lua compiler that has libraries to interact with Skype? I wanted to message people automatically at a certain time. Please give me a link.

Comment: Are you asking for lua libraries that interact with skype? What does the bit about a "compiler" have to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [skoope](https://github.com/Noiwex/skoope), you might be able to use it, or it could at least give you an example of using Lua to interact with Skype.